# Populate combox with only items that get checked in a checklistbox

Tags: vb.net

I want the checked items in the checklistbox to only populate the combobox.

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To chekBoxList1.Items.Count - 1
        If chekBoxList1.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
            comboBox1.Items(i).Add = chekBoxList1.Items(i)
        End If
    Next
```

This code gets highlighted for an error:
       `cboShipment.Items(i).Add = chkLstShipments.Items(i)`

The Error:

> "InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index"

Any suggestion for correction is appreciated!

Comment: The -1 is not the issue as its giving the error on the first loop around not the last. I think you need to remove the (i) from the comboBox1.Items(i).Add as you are adding an item, you shouldnt have to specify its order

Comment: ahh good thinking, thank you

Comment: @KennethSalomon what about the `=`?

Comment: well I tried what you said and got this while the same code was highlighted: "Argument not specified for parameter 'item' of 'Public Function Add(item As Object) As Integer' "

Comment: @NCarpenter `Add` is a method, you dont need the =, instead wrap the parameter in brackets

Comment: NCarpenter let me know how that goes. I can submit it as an answer if it fixes your problem.

@NickA The error is specific enough we can eliminate that from the issue. We need to focus on things that may not need or are being referenced improperly by the use of an index. I see your post though and I think you are right, the equals might need to be removed and the second half of the line enclosed in parenthesis.

Comment: @NCarpenter Submitted a proper answer for you. I am happy to help.

Comment: Yep you guys are both correct, there were two errors with that code, Kenneth solved the first and Nick solved the second error. I needed to use ComboBox1.Items.Add(chekBoxList1.Items(i))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While others in the comments suggested the second problem, you do not need to specify an index when using .Add().

To fix this completely, the final line should look like such:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(chekBoxList1.Items(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use     ComboBox1.Items.Add(chekBoxList1.Items(i))